# What Does 1F represent in the following code?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm learning Unity 5 and I know nothing about Programming. But I have watched a tutorial on "How to make a Day/Night Cycle" in Unity and the tutor wrote this script to cycle between moon and sun.. Here's the code:

```
    using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class sun : MonoBehaviour {

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        transform.RotateAround(Vector3.zero, Vector3.right, 1f * Time.deltaTime);
        transform.LookAt(Vector3.zero);
    }
}
```

And the speed of cycling is depends on **1F** which we can change the any number.. But I don't know how long does it take to do 1F rotation between sun and moon! So can you tell me this number in something like seconds or minutes ? So I can be able to set it myself to a custom duration. Thanks in advance

Comment: Your title doesn't match your actual question

Comment: Sorry ,I'm not a native English speaker so I couldn't explain my question very well

Comment: 1f is a floating point value of 1. In this case, it likely means 1 degree per second, which is then multiplied by the DeltaTime to enable a smooth 1 degree per second rotation.

Comment: Here are all the suffixes for built-in types: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfft1t3c.aspx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `f` after a numeric literal signifies that the value is to be explicitly treated as a [`float`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1e65aza.aspx).  In this case, if you were to write `1` instead of `1f`, that value would be treated as an `int`.  Generally, this isn't a big deal as ints will automatically cast themselves into floats in situations where such a casting is required.  The time when you're really going to need this is if you are ever writing real literals, i.e. `1.5`.  `1.5` by itself will be treated as a `double` instead of a `float`.

This is very significant for Unity programming, as many objects in the Unity library do their computations with floats instead of doubles.  If you try something like `transform.RotateAround(Vector3.zero, Vector3.right, 1.5 * Time.deltaTime)`, you will get an error when the game tries to build, as doubles will not automatically cast themselves to floats without an explicit cast.  To use real literals in many calls to Unity functions, you will need to designate your literals as floats with the `f` notation you are asking about.  `new transform.RotateAround(Vector3.zero, Vector3.right, 1.5f * Time.deltaTime)` will work just fine.

In this case, since it is multiplying by [`Time.deltaTime`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-deltaTime.html) (another float), you will have a rotation of 1 degree per second.  `Time.deltaTime` is the number of seconds that have passed since the last frame, so when you multiply a value of `v` by `Time.deltaTime` and add it up each frame, you will get a steady progression of `v` per second.

Answer (score 7):

In C#, a lowercase f after a number indicates that the value should be treated as a float.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1e65aza.aspx

By multiplying this by the deltaTime value, it's rotating either 1 degree or 1 radian per second. I'm unfamiliar with Unity and can't speak authoritatively on the subject.

Comment: casing doesn't matter

Comment: both f & F can be used to indicate a float. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/lexical-structure

Answer (score 0):

1f is a literal that means a floating point value (datatype is [float](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1e65aza.aspx)) of 1.

In this case, it is being used to represent a floating point degree angle value of 1, which is then multiplied by Time.deltaTime to get a smooth rotation of 1 degree per second.

See Unity's [RotateAround](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.RotateAround.html) documentation for further info.

Answer (score -12):

It's a hexadecimal number, 1F = 31

Comment: Hex numbers are prefixed with `0x` in .NET